# Can I ask a question about overall architecture without much specific code?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

I *have* code, but my question is about overall design patterns. Ideally, I would ask a question describing the design decisions made in my project but would have minimal actual code samples.

Is this acceptable/encouraged?

Answer (score 14):

No. It sounds like your question would be better suited to [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). In Code Review, we focus on concrete details — and that means we want to see your code.