# Including function implementations if I need advice about architecture/design/file hierarchy?

Tags: discussion

I have a program that loads data from CSV files, processes it, and returns CSV files as output. The program is divided into a series of functions that are housed in various files.

What I'm interested in is getting feedback on the file structure I'm using, and the separation into functions. A sort of "architecture/design review," so to speak.

So, my question is: Would it be better to upload the code with the implementation of each function for simplicity, or would it be better to omit it to keep the complexity low?

Comment: Related: [Can I ask a question about overall architecture without much specific code?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2008/52915)

Answer (score 3):

Upload the code. The code limit is fairly high, and the more you omit, the more ambiguity there is in your architectural description. A good code review will cover both the architecture as well as more granular details.